# GSON parser check for object or string

Tags: java, json, gson

so I have an application that is parsing a JSON file using GSON.

The file is being upgraded, but we want the parser to remain backwards comatable.

The original file contained a list of string, while the new will have a list of objects due to adding another data point.

Object for old file:

```
private static class parsedata {
    String id;
    List<String> stringData;
}
```

Objects for new file would be more like:

```
private static class parsedata {
    String id;
    List<Data> data;
}

private static class Data {
    String id;
    Long dataNum;
}
```

What would be a good method to ensure that this remains backwards compatible in the case that the new data (dataNum) is not present.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `in the case that the new data (dataNum) is not present.`. Is it still going to be a JSON object like `[{"id":"asd"}, "id":"qwe", "dataNum":"haha"}]` simply missing `dataNum`? Or is it going to be a JSON string `["asd", "qwe"]`?

Comment: If the new data is not present, it is just a list of strings, so the latter ["String1","String2"]

Comment: There is no good solution for this then. You can have a custom `TypeAdapter` that can generate a `String` value or a `Data` value depending. This means that your root POJO will need to have a `List<Object>` and you will constantly have to check the type of that Object. I advise against this 100%.